# Optimizing Applications on Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, c, optimization, android-ndk

My application for Android NDK uses a single Open Source library in C. When it work, this library is too much load on the processor. Questions:

1. How understand what components of the library take the most pressure?
2. Is there any method to optimize? LOCAL_ARM_MODE: = arm greatly improves the performance?

Comment: What open source library are you trying to use? If you name it, we can mostly provide more specific infomration. If it is a video codec for example, then the answer could be that video encoding inherently requires a lot of CPU power due to the large amount of data and computationally intensive work.

Comment: I use the audio library. It includes all the other codecs, such libraries - libflac, libmp3lame, ffmpeg ...

Comment: So this library for decoding audio takes a lot of CPU. How can I reduce the consumption of the CPU??

Comment: Can you be somewhat more specific about what you plan to do with the audio library: Encoding, decoding, analyzing or transforming audio? In real-time (as fast as you listen to an audio sample) or several times faster? Do you have an idea which of the libraries you mention is the bottleneck? In general such libraries might require that a few core routines are optimized manually (possibly in assembler to take advantage of special multimedia instruction). If possible, try to use the built-in functionality. Android natively supports many audio formats (at least for playback).

Comment: I only need to decode and then playback using AudioTrack. likely decoding will be faster, but you can at the same rate. advantage of Android can not, be it with the help of these libraries. I do not know what a library is so very heavy, but with Vav file and Flac file the same result. There must be some methods without rewriting code libraries, which is difficult for me??

Answer (score 2):

There some tricks that can optimize your Android native code without too much efforts:

- turn on level 3 compiler optimizations using `-O3` switch
- turn off string aliasing `-fno-strict-aliasing` (or you can turn it
  on if you are following the C-aliasing rules)
- turn on floating-point instructions support `-mfpu=vfp
  -mfloat-abi=softfp`

Comment: Where to add these flags?

Comment: CPPFLAGS += -fno-strict-aliasing -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp